# python - making a multipanel bar chart with different categories for each panel

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

I would like to make multipanel bar charts in python, with different categories for each panel. Below, I'll show a example of how I can do this with ggplot2 in R. I am looking for any approachin python that can do the equivalent. So far I have struggled to do this in python-ggplot and seaborn and base matplotlib so far without luck.

You can see an earlier attempt at this in a related post of mine:
[using facet_wrap with categorical variables that differ between facet panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463191/using-facet-wrap-with-categorical-variables-that-differ-between-facet-panes)

In this post, I am now asking if there is any way at all to make the kind of plots I am looking for in python (rather than just trying to get a specific approach to work).

Ok: example in R:

```
animal = c('sheep', 'sheep', 'cow', 'cow', 'horse', 'horse', 'horse')
attribute = c('standard', 'woolly', 'brown', 'spotted', 'red', 'brown', 'grey')
population = c(12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5)
animalCounts = data.frame(animal,attribute,population)

ggplot(aes(x = attribute, weight = population), data = animalCounts) + geom_bar() + 
facet_wrap(~animal, scales = "free") + scale_y_continuous ( limits= c(0,12))
```

[image: barchart that I would like to make in python]

I can create a similar data-frame in python

```
animal = pd.Series(['sheep', 'sheep', 'cow', 'cow', 'horse', 'horse', 'horse'], dtype = 'category')
attribute = pd.Series(['standard', 'woolly', 'brown', 'spotted', 'red', 'brown', 'grey'], dtype = 'category')
population = pd.Series([12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5])
animalCounts = pd.DataFrame({'animal' : animal, 'attribute' : attribute, 'population': population})
```

Any help getting a comparable figure in python would be highly appreciated. Imaginary bonus points if I don't have to use rpy2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the issue already presented in the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463191/using-facet-wrap-with-categorical-variables-that-differ-between-facet-panes), python ggplot cannot use `facet_wrap`.

Therefore using standard pandas / matplotlib techniques would be an option.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

animal = pd.Series(['sheep', 'sheep', 'cow', 'cow', 'horse', 'horse', 'horse'], dtype = 'category')
attribute = pd.Series(['standard', 'woolly', 'brown', 'spotted', 'red', 'brown', 'grey'], dtype = 'category')
population = pd.Series([12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal' : animal, 'attribute' : attribute, 'population': population})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
for i, (name, group) in enumerate(df.groupby("animal")):
    axes[i].set_title(name)
    group.plot(kind="bar", x = "attribute", y="population", ax=axes[i], legend=False)
    axes[i].set_ylabel("count")
    axes[i].set_xlabel("")

axes[1].set_xlabel("attribute")    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]